# Integrating GDB on a binary embedded firmware

Tags: assembly, gdb, embedded, gdbserver

I am working with a router that has an ARC600 chipset controlling the antenna. The firmware that is loaded onto the antenna is a binary blob, but I am able to write my own ARC600 assembly and execute it on the embedded system. Now I would love to debug it using gdb if possible:

- Is there any way of compiling a kind of gdb server inside the binary?
- Since the embedded chipset does not have any interface, all communications to the host should be done by writing/reading to a shared memory location

Is this even doable?

Comment: Generally if you have an ELF file etc, good embedded debuggers can open that one and then connect to the running target without downloading new code. I don't know if it is possible with gdb.

Comment: The problem is that that would require a JTAG interface, and I do not have access to one. What I hops is to integrate the debugger through writing/reading to memory.

Comment: GDB uses ["gdbstub"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Remote-Stub.html) to communicate with the debugger on your development host. There is not much to implement, I have done this some 20 years ago for a 68040 system, but IIRC you need an interrupt if you want to support all features. Anyway, you need a communication channel.

Comment: Oh nice, I will read about it. I can manage to do an interrupt since I can add my custom code, hopefully I can integrate this, thanks.